# Getting Widget ID's in a Loop

Tags: android, loops, button, attributes, widget

I need to find a way to modify attributes of widgets from within a for loop.  In particular, I need to go through and dynamically change the text on each button in a series.

Changing the text is of no issue, I can do it with a single button very easily, but how can I get this loop to correctly find the next button?  It seems to need to be a direct reference to the button, but there's no way for me to just increment something and get the next button ID.

In a worst case scenario I can just take care of every button individually, but this is obviously very sloppy and that's not the kind of code I want to get used to creating, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to get all the children in a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) such as a `LinearLayout`. You can use something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
    if(child.getClass() == Button.class)
    {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: I had some issues getting little things working, but thanks to your snippet I'm good to go for this bit.  Many thanks for your help.